# Datastore: Cannot get more than 1000 keys in a single call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I am using spring boot and google datastore. Below is my main entity which is referencing other entity "patients".

```
@Entity(name = "depart_list")
public class DepartList {
  @Id private String compositeKey;
  @Reference private List<Patient> patients;
}


@Entity(name = "patient")
public class Patient {
  @Id private String compositeKey;
  private String cid;
  private LocalDate date;
```

Jpa method:

```
Page<DepartList> findByCompositeKey(String compositeKey, Pageable pageable);
```

Now the problem is I only have 1 result in datastore against depart_list BUT the referenced patient list values are more than 1000 and I don't know how to apply limit/page to that. which is why I am getting below exception.

```
com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: cannot get more than 1000 keys in a single call, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to separate your list into multiple lists.  E.g.

```
@LazyReference
List<Patient> patients0;
@LazyReference
List<Patient> patients1;
```

You can find the source code for resolving reference properites at:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/d969b6c4454d1f49b38e7254bfec4c52d9db9943/spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/datastore/core/DatastoreTemplate.java#L690